# mysql - insert select from two tables with user input

Tags: mysql, select, jdbc, insert, user-input

I have two tables:

- a customer table with attributes: `firstName, lastName, address, email, password`.
- a creditcards table with attributes: `id, firstName, lastName`.

The goal is I need to insert a customer into the customer table only if he/she exists in the creditcards table. All the information are from user's input.

This is what I try to do:

```
    IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT first_name, last_name 
    FROM creditcards 
    WHERE creditcards.first_name = ? 
    AND creditcards.last_name = ?
    )
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name, address,email,password)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
    END
```

I also did the setString for the seven "?". But it complains there is syntax error in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `IF` control block outside of functions in MySQL. That is the reason behind your syntax error. A way to construct your query would be a `SELECT` inside an `INSERT`, something like the following:

```
    INSERT INTO customers (`first_name`,`last_name`,`address`,`email`,`password`)
    SELECT first_name, last_name, address, email, password
    FROM (SELECT ? as first_name, ? as last_name, ? as address, ? as email, ? as password) a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM creditcards b WHERE a.first_name = b.first_name AND a.last_name=b.last_name);
```